# Silverlight copy dialog makes IE11 freeze

Tags: silverlight, copy, internet-explorer-11

We are having problem with a Silverlight 5 app and IE11.
Suddenly, it's no longer possible to copy-and-paste from a Silverlight application to the clipboard, after upgrading to IE11.

When the Silverlight dialog that asks you for the right to access the clip-board appears, then IE11 freezes. This behaviour has also been verified on IE11 och two different Win 8.1 computers.

We have also tried to add the site to trusted sites, and 'Allow programatic access to clipboard" to Enabled. But it dosnt help.

Any suggestions?
Anyone knowing if this is something Microsoft is addressing?

/Erik

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, running IE as administrator ended up clearing up the freezing issue.

From there you can then check the box to [remember my answer], click [yes] to allow clipboard access for this site, then restart IE (non-admin) and it won't freeze when accessing the clipboard.